# Drag and drop of controls on browser using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am displaying some controls on page. My requirement is in browser client can able to change the position of controls. How can achieve this through JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to adopt existing JS frameworks like jQuery UI to implement this feature as dragging/dropping is built into it.
Link :

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Thank you. I m also thinking same.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to bind the position of the elements to the mouse cursor on mousedown, and drop them at their destination on mouse up.